# C# Merge 2 list of IP

Tags: c#, linq, merge

I mm using this model :

```
public class IPList
{
    public List<string> websites { get; set; }
    public int total_websites { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

The list has the following values :

```
[{
    "websites": ["test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com", "test4.com"],
    "total_websites": 4,
    "ip": "104.130.124.96"
}, {
    "websites": ["test5.com"],
    "total_websites": 1,
    "ip": "104.130.124.80"
}, {
    "websites": ["test6.com"],
    "total_websites": 1,
    "ip": "104.130.124.70"
}]
```

I would like to have a new list with all IPs in the Range `104.130.124.x` (`104.130.124.0 to 104.130.124.255`).

What i ve done:

```
List<IPList> NewIPList = new List<IPList>();
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    string TempIP = "104.130.124." + i;
    IPListTake10 TempIpList = IPList.Where(p => p.ip == TempIP).FirstOrDefault();
    if (TempIpList != null)
    {
        NewIPList.Add(new IPList{ ip = TempIP, total_websites = TempIpList.total_websites, websites = TempIpList.websites });
    }
    else
    {
        NewIPList.Add(new IPList{ ip = TempIP, total_websites = 0});
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do that ?

Maybe by using one of those methods :
http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c

- Lists and LINQ merge
- Dictionary merge
- HashSet and IEqualityComparer
- LINQ Union and IEqualityComparer

Comment: Why not ```NewIPList = IPList.Where(x=>x.ip.StartsWith("104.130.124.")).ToList()``` ?

Comment: First thing I can spot, remove the setter for total_websites and use websites in the getter.

Comment: Why don't you use a `IPAddress` instead of `String` for the `Ip`-property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try following

```
var IPList = new List<IPList>() { new IPList() {ip="104.130.124.10", total_websites=10}};

var NewIPList = Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
        .Select(x => $"104.130.124.{x}")
        .Select(x => IPList.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ip == x) ?? new IPList() {ip=x, total_websites=0})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, looking better than my solution!